# "Prime decomposition" for the profinite integers, adeles, or p-adics?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory, profinite-groups, adeles

The strictly positive integers can be decomposed into a product of prime powers. Likewise, the positive rationals can be decomposed into a product of (possibly negative) prime powers.

Another way to state this is that the underlying multiplicative monoids are free and admit the primes as a basis.

If negative integers or rationals are allowed, then we no longer get a free monoid. But, we can still get a suitable prime decomposition if we create an additional "basis" element, representing -1, that takes exponents in $\Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z$.

I'm wondering if a similar sort of decomposition exists for any of the more interesting structures thrown around in number theory, namely

1. The profinite integers, and/or its group of units
2. The ring of adeles, and/or its group of units
3. The field of p-adic numbers for some p

I'm particularly interested in the case where the "basis" is countable, like the primes themselves.

Now, since these are all uncountable, it's clear that a decomposition into a direct sum of countable groups won't work. But perhaps we can allow infinitely many non-zero exponents, or allow the exponents to take values in some interesting group. Does anything like this work?

The [supernatural numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernatural_number) seem related here, but I can't tell exactly what the relationship is, or if they embed into one of the groups mentioned (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a notion of [unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain), which is a commutative [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) whose nonzero elements admit unique prime factorizations up to units. (If we don't ignore units then there's no hope of getting uniqueness.)

The $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ have this property mostly by virtue of having a lot of units: every $p$-adic integer is uniquely of the form $p^n$ times a unit. In fact $p$ is the only prime in the $p$-adics! This reflects the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a [local ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring).

The group of units is well understood. Let me assume that $p$ is odd because something annoying happens when $p = 2$. The group of units is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ times the subgroup of units congruent to $1 \bmod p$. This subgroup is in turn isomorphic to the *additive* group $\mathbb{Z}_p$, with the isomorphism given by the exponential

$$\mathbb{Z}_p \ni a \mapsto (1 + p)^a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}.$$

In particular, it is "topologically generated" by $1 + p$.

The profinite integers and the adeles don't fall into this framework because they are not integral domains. In a ring that's not an integral domain it's very unclear what one ought to mean by unique prime factorization of a zero divisor. Nevertheless, since the multiplicative monoid and group of units functors both send products to products, once you've understood what's going on for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ you more or less understand what's going on in these more complicated cases.

Comment: The rationals aren't a UFD, but they admit the sort of structure I'm talking about, right? Likewise with the supernatural numbers.

Comment: Sorry, to be technically correct, fields ARE UFD's -- but everything's a unit! Still...

Comment: I guess the thing I'm really interested in is finding a decomposition for the group of units, as a starting point.

Comment: @Matt: I give such a decomposition above for the $p$-adic integrs, and from there you can infer what's going on for the profinite integers, the adeles, and the $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: I'm confused because [this site](http://www.noncommutative.org/supernatural-numbers-and-adeles/) details here how $\hat{\Bbb Z} / (\hat{\Bbb Z})^\times$ is isomorphic to the group of supernaturals, which is sort of the "extended" prime decomposition I was looking for. But I'm having a lot of trouble seeing the big picture of what you wrote and how it relates to this. Is there some further decomposition of the additive group of $\Bbb Z_p$ that makes the connection more apparent?

Comment: @Mike: the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is complicated as an abstract group; as far as I know it has no simpler description than "the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}_p$." In particular, since it is uncountable, it cannot even be countably generated. However, with its natural topology, it is *topologically cyclic*; that is, $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ generates a dense subgroup. This is why I said above that the subgroup of units congruent to $1 \bmod p$ is topologically geneated by $1 + p$.

Comment: Anyway, can you ask a more specific question? There are a lot of things you could be curious about here and I don't know which one you really care about.

Comment: Here's where I'm coming from - the positive group of multiplicative rationals admits a decomposition for every element into the form $2^{e_2} \cdot 3^{e_3} \cdot 5^{e_5} ...$. We can write that as $(e_2, e_3, e_5, ...)$ for short. Treated as a Z-module, the dual module consists of "ideal rational numbers" which don't require all but finitely many exponents to be zero. The dual module is uncountable, but still admits the primes as a "Schauder basis" (slight abuse of terminology). (cont'd)

Comment: This is a particularly natural structure that's reminiscent of the supernatural numbers. The supernatural numbers also have the primes as a "Schauder basis", except where exponents are now allowed to take values in $\Bbb N \cup {\infty}$. The supernatural numbers are then related to the profinite integers and adeles, which I've never quite been able to understand. So I'm trying to see if a similar Schauder basis exists for these other weird multiplicative groups that one can construct from the integers via the inverse limit construction as a way of understanding them.

Comment: @Mike: the profinite integers are isomorphic to the direct product $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$ over all the $p$-adic integers, essentially by the Chinese remainder theorem. Each component of this direct product admits a decomposition as $p^n$ times a $p$-adic unit (where $n = \infty$ corresponds to $0$). So you can associate to any profinite integer a supernatural number, namely the $n$s that appear in this decomposition, ignoring the various units that arise.

Comment: OK, that made it click and now I got it. So you can also embed the supernaturals into the profinite integers this way by choosing the unit "1" for each entry in the tuple. But then the embedding from naturals -> supernaturals -> profinite integers is completely different from the usual embedding from naturals -> profinite integers. Right? I think that's why I was getting tripped up before.

Comment: @Mike: yes, it's different. In the usual embedding a natural number $n$ gets sent to (for each prime $p$) $p^k$ times whatever $p$-adic unit $\frac{n}{p^k}$ ends up being (where $p^k$ is the greatest power of $p$ dividing $n$).